# Homomorphism and irreducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $Y: G/N→ GL_d(\mathbb{C})$ be a representation defined by $Y(gN) = X(g)$.
Where $N = {\{g\in G: X(g) = I}\}$ is the kernel.

Prove that $Y$ is irreducible if and only if $X$ is.

attempt: A nonzero representation $V$ of $G$ is said to be irreducible if its only subrepresentation are zero and V itself.

let  $Y: G/N→ GL_d(\mathbb{C})$.

Suppose $X$ is irreducible , can someone please help me with the converse? 
I am stuck on that one.
Thank you!

Comment: You should define all the terms you're using.  For example, how are we supposed to know what $X$ is?

Comment: Do you mean that $I$ is the identity matrix?  I don't think writing $N = I$ makes sense here, because $N$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sometimes useful to think of representations in the following way.  Let $V$ be the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}^d$.  A representation of $G$ is a group homomorphism $X: G \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{C})$, right?  So, for each $g \in G$, $X(g)$ is an invertible matrix.  But invertible matrices $A$ correspond to linear transformations $T_A:V \rightarrow V$ which are invertible.

A *vector subspace* of $V$ is a nonempty subset $W$ of $V$ which is closed under scalar multiplication and addition.  A vector subspace $W$ is *$G$-invariant* (with respect to a given representation $X: G \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{C})$) if for all $g \in G$, and all $w \in W$, the element $T_{X(g)}(w)$ still lies in $W$.

To say that a representation $X: G \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{C})$ of a group $G$ is *irreducible* is to say that the only $G$-invariant subspaces of $V$ are the zero subspace and $V$ itself.

Now the induced representation $Y: G/N \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{C})$ of $G/N$ is basically the 'same' as the representation of $G$, except we are now considering the inputs to be cosets (special subsets) of $G$ instead of elements of $G$.  In other words, $Y(gN) = X(g)$.  So, it is intuitively obvious (and you should carefully prove) that a subspace $W$ of $V$ is $G$-invariant (with respect to the representation $X$) if and only if it is $G/N$-invariant (with respect to the representation $Y$).

Hence $X$ is irreducible if and only if $Y$ is irreducible.